# Link in clickable table cell issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a clickable cell with a link inside it, something like the following:

```
<html><body>
<table><tr><td onclick="alert('Cell click event fired.');">
Blah blah blah 
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Link click event fired.'); return false;">Here</a>
</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

The problem is when I click on the link both onclick events fire. How do I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT:**

A jQuery solution is acceptable if someone can give me an example of how to do that.

Comment: So what does the `onlick` event do exactly?

Comment: ...or should I say what exactly does one need to do to trigger *"onlick"*? ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop propagation of the event.

**EDIT:** Since you asked about jQuery, you could delete the inline `onclick` attributes and assign the handlers like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('table td').click( doSomething )
           .find('a').click( doSomethingElse );

        function doSomething() {
            alert('something');
        }

        function doSomethingElse(e) {
            alert('somethingElse');
            return false;  // prevent default behavior and bubbling on the <a>
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note that this will assign click events to *every* `<td>` and their descendant `<a>` elements. You'll need to provide more specific markup for a more specific solution.

And don't forget to import the jQuery library *before* your code.

---

To do this in a cross-browser compatible manner, do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7u9Jg/1/

```
<a href="#test" onclick="doSomethingElse(event);">Here</a>
```

---

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('something');
}

function doSomethingElse(e) {
         // make sure the event doesn't bubble
    if( e ) e.stopPropagation();               // W3C Compatible
    else window.event.cancelBubble = true;     // IE Compatible

    alert('somethingElse');
}
```

Comment: So @patrick dw is "event" always available as a parameter name for the Function instance (or rough equivalent) built automatically for the inline handler code?

Comment: Is there a simple way that jQuery can handle this situation? I would accept that as an answer as well.

Comment: Should be. I haven't done extensive testing, but the inline handler is just wrapped in an anonymous function that is assigned to the `onclick` property. Browsers that support an event parameter should have it set in the function that is assigned, so the inline call picks that up.

Comment: Ah excellent, I didn't realize jQuery did a little more than simply bind the function to the event with the `click()` call. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Spencer: Yeah, that's all it takes. It doesn't need to be a named function either. You can pass an anonymous function, but I'm a believer in naming your functions. :o)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The "inner" element should be set up such that the handler returns `false`:</strike>

```
Blah blah blah <a href="#" onclick="doSomethingElse(); return false;">Here</a>
```

That will prevent the default "bubbling" of the event up through the DOM. (It'll also prevent the default behavior for the `<a>` tag, which in this case is nothing anyway.)

You can also do this by calling the ".preventDefault()" method on the event object from within the handler, but you'd have to change more code to do that, and it doesn't seem worth it (here).

I do this a lot, seems like :-)  Anyway, returning `false` does definitely prevent default action, but it doesn't cancel bubbling. To do that the handler can call ".stopPropagation()" (or in old IE browsers set the "cancelBubble" flag on the event object, or something like that).  However to do that you have to register your event handlers differently (well you might not *have* to, but I don't recall the trick necessary to get at the event object with in-line handler code.)

I really hate answering questions by plugging frameworks, but event handling (and dealing with the vagaries of all the different browsers) is one of the things I happily delegate to a framework; almost anything you choose is going to make event handling easier and more reliable.

Comment: Are you sure that `return false;` prevents bubbling? It does in jQuery, but I didn't think it did outside the library. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8mZCd/)

Comment: It's a Javascript/DOM event handling thing, as far as I know. I can rig up a jsfiddle and see ...

Comment: @Pointy: See my updated comment above. I included an example. I'm pretty sure `return false;` only prevents default behavior.

Comment: Hmm @patrick it does seem to prevent default handling, but I'm not so sure it stops bubbling ... still trying to make sure I didn't do something dumb :-)

Comment: Is there a simple way that jQuery can handle this situation? I would accept that as an answer as well.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport well when you set up event handlers via jQuery methods, then its code will honor that `false` return value convention. It also provides your event handlers with a "improved" event object that has cross-browser reliable versions of the "preventDefault" and "stopPropagation" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what you want? By including your onclick event in the `<td>` as well, you're telling the browser to do exactly that.. can you consolidate the code you need into your `<a>` onclick?

Comment: The anchor tag may be wrapped around some little in-line gadget, like something to do script-driven page updates, while the cell overall might do different things.  Consider little "up" and "down" buttons on numeric fields, maybe.  I don't know in this case, of course :-)